# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PostsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
# posts_controller.rb
 def show
   @comment = @post.comments.build
  end!
```

[image]

I generated comments_controller.rb and so on by scaffolding. 
Then this error occurred.

I am not sure what to do.
How can I solve this error ?

```
#comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:user_name, :body, :post_id)
    end
end
```

```
#posts_controller.rb
# GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
   @comment = @post.comments.build
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :subject, :body, :picture)
    end

    def video
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your post.  Please review to make sure that everything is the way you intended.

Comment: Issue seems to be in your `Comment` model. Did you remember to put `belongs_to :post`? (notice singular, not plural). Are you sure a `post_id` column was created in the database table? (check `db/schema.rb`). What's the url that gave you that error?

Answer (score 0):

Before going in more details just a suggestion. I assume you're using @post to use it in the form on post page. Instead of that you can use symbol

```
<%= form_for :comment, method: :post, url: comments_path do |f| %>
```

or alternatively if you're using nested routes

```
<%= form_for [@post, :comment], method: :post, url: comments_path do |f| %>
```

This will submit to the controller for comments.

Also, make sure by checking your schema.rb that your comment model includes post_id

Comment: the last line of your answer is likely the real issue. And I would always recommend using the instance over the symbol.

Comment: I understand that you want an instance hence recycling of the form partial. 

The problem I always run into is that you're ending up having whole bunch of declarations in the controller that are not really doing anything useful. 

I use symbol occasionally when I have whole bunch of forms for new record on a page.

Answer (score 0):

[**foriegn_key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

The problem will be your `comments` table won't have `post_id` present.

When 
you use [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in Rails, although it will *appear* to be magic, it wil rely on old-school relational database architecture. The main component of which being `primary_key`s (to identify individual records) and `foreign_key`s (to identify associative records)

--

If you want to be able to associate two models together, you need to make sure you have the corresponding foriegn_keys:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | post_id | other | attributes | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Bottom line is that you need to make sure you have `post_id` column in your comments table. If you don't, you should perform a migration to insert it:

```
#db/migrate/new_migration.rb
Class NewMigration
   def self.up
      add_column :comments, :post_id, :string
   end
end
```